# Where can I find the alias file in macOS

Tags: terminal, command-line, zsh, alias

When running the command `alias` in `Terminal.app`, it outputs a few aliases that I am unable to find within my `$HOME` and `/etc` directories. The output of the current `alias` is

```
run-help=man
which-command=whence
```

Running each with grep (`grep 'run-help' *` and `grep 'which-command' *`) in `/etc` and `~/` did not give an output. Within the `~/` and `/etc` directories and checking the terminal profiles, I still am not able to see the aliases defined anywhere. There happens to be no rc files either.

Where can I find the `alias` alias definitions (other than from the command itself)?

Running a fresh install of Mac OS Ventura 13.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two alias definitions are actually built-in to `alias` itself, which in turn is just a `zsh` built-in. So you would find those aliases buried within the `zsh` binary in `/bin/zsh`.

In source code form, you can find those definitions here:

https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/zsh/blob/c808e6d6b8b0d1b186cac0e691d52b044fa4ea03/zsh/Src/hashtable.c#L1211

Comment: Amazing! How could such a bizarre design idea slip through all reviews, when zsh was developed???

Comment: Well, it's your opinion that it is bizarre - but you're quite mistaken in believing that this went through multiple design reviews. This particular feature was made around 1990-1992 - it was a different time quite literally.

Comment: `ksh` also has default aliases, it's not something that's unique to `zsh`.

Comment: @user1934428 I should have added before, you can always `unalias` the default aliases, if you don't want them there.  Both of them are mentioned in the man page.